# C# - Converting from string to my object

Tags: c#, string, object, type-conversion

In my code I load a text file and read it, looking for specific parameters. After I get them, I save them as `string`, and now I need to send them to a set-method, that only gets `MyProperties` type variables. ("MyProperties" is an enum class, and the method that receives the parameter needs to get an enum of this type)

So my question is: how can I convert them from `string` to `MyProperties` type?

Reading the file:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText("C:/avi/properties/" + propertiesFile);
```

After I get a parameter I need, I save it in a `string` var named `mode`.

```
string mode; // ---> Needs to be "MyProperties mode;"
vpa.Set(MyProperties.Mode, mode);
```

Solutions like checking `if (mode.equals("string"))` or "switch" are too long because there is a lot to check.

Comment: Maybe look into some form of serialization such as XML or JSON.

Comment: That's deserialization, not conversion. Unless by `conversion` you actually mean calling a property setter

Comment: could you show us how you "save them as string" ?

Comment: Is Mode an enumeration?

Comment: @MongZhu i edited the question.

Comment: @EricBurdo at first i get out of the text file a list which is an enumeration, then i get the parameters out of this list, and saves them as string.

Comment: what you posted is how you **load** the file not the saving part. Do you just simply write the values into the file? can you post an example of a saved property. How does it look in the file?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, i simply write the values into a text file, and then i use Regex to look for what i need that text file.
For example i save line in the text file like this:
"Brightness 20 Auto"
Then i get the "20" out and convert it to int, and i get the "Auto" out as a string too, and need to convert it to MyProperties.

Comment: does `MyProperties` not have a suitable constructor?

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer MyProperties is only an enum class, and the method that receives the parameters can only get an enum of this type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been able to find an answer on another post, this is what i used:

```
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
MyProperties prop = (MyProperties)converter.ConvertFrom(mode);
```

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution.  That's what I was headed towards... knowing what type of object (in this case, a specific enumeration) makes it easier to figure out how to convert from a string to that object type.  Great find!

Comment: ok I misunderstood you quite hard. Nice solution that you found. I was aiming for to set the value of the property in an object. I did not get that you actually already have this method to set the value. and that you need to convert a string to an enum. Cool that you found a solution